# How to extract a function out of a monolithic piece of code?

Tags: c, function

It is said it is better to create many small function rather than a few big ones. So if a function grows too big, one might want to extract a piece of it to a separate function. But how is it done technically? There are many ways to exchange data between functions, when to use each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few simple mechanical rules one needs to follow.

1. Have data that the new function needs to use, but doesn't need to change? Pass it *by value* or by *pointer to const*. (Most people will tell you that everything is passed by value in C, there is no such thing as passing by pointer. I just made up this term for convenience. Passing X by pointer is the same as passing the pointer to X by value). Example: finding a maximum value in an array.

- Before:

  ```
  int array[MAX_ARRAY];
  size_t actual_size;
  // array initialised here
  ...
  // want to extract this piece of code
  // the function needs to look at the array and the size,
  // but not change them
  int maxVal = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < actual_size; ++i) {
    if (array[i] > maxVal) maxVal = array[i];
  }
  ```
- After:

  ```
  // Passing the array by const pointer (cannot pass arrays by value)
  // and size by value
  // In case of arrays we pass a pointer to the first element, rather than
  // a pointer to the array itself.
  int findMax(const int* array, size_t size) {
    int maxVal = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < actual_size; ++i) {
      if (array[i] > maxVal) maxVal = array[i];
    }
    return maxVal;
  }
  ...
  // An array decays to a pointer to its first element
  int maxVal = findMax(array, actual_size);
  ```

  Here we have two things to pass to the function: the array and the array size. The array is passed by *pointer to const* (you cannot pass arrays by value) and the size is passed by value. If you have a choice between passing by value and passing by const pointer, which means you have a `struct` or a `union`, choose pass by value if the value is reasonably small (a few integers or pointers). Otherwise pass by pointer to const.

2. Have a single small piece data that the new function needs to initialise/create/compute? *Return* it from the function. The example above above also illustrates return from a function. Here is another example of returning a value:

- Before:

  ```
  size_t array_size;
  // Want to extract this piece of code
  // 'array' should be initialised inside, and used outside afterwards
  int* array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(*array));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    array[i] = rand();
  ```
- After:

  ```
  // Make 'array' the return value of the function
  int* create_random_array(size_t array_size) {
    int* array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(*array));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
      array[i] = rand();
    return array;
  }
  ...
  int* array = create_random_array(array_size);

  /* INCORRECT, won't work, never do this */ 
  void create_random_array(int* array, size_t array_size) {
    array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(*array));
  ...
  int* array;
  create_random_array (array, array_size);
  ```

3. Have a piece of data that the function needs to look at before changing it? Have a big piece of data that the function needs to initialise? Have several small pieces of data that the function needs to initialise? In each case, pass by pointer (to non-const). Example: inserting a node into a linked list.

- Before:

  ```
  Node* head = NULL;
  // maybe insert a few elements
  ...
  // want to extract this piece of code
  // head is initialised above, may be changed in the function,
  // and then used after the call
  Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
  ```
- After:

  ```
  // Passing the head of the list by pointer, even though
  // it is a pointer itself. This results in a pointer-to-pointer
  // and two stars in the declaration of pNode
  void insertFront(node** pHead, int data) {
    Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *pHead;
    *pHead = new_node;
  }
  ...
  insertFront(&head, data);

  // Variant that uses a combination of techniques above instead
  // Pass old head by value, return new head
  // The same technique is used by e.g. realloc: old pointer by value,
  // return new pointer. If your function wraps realloc and adds 
  // a few bells and whistles, consider using this technique
  node* insertFront(node* head, int data) {
    Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
  }
  ...
  head = insertFront(head, data);

  /* INCORRECT, won't work, never do this */ 
  void insertFront(node* head, int data) { ...
  ```

  Another example: find a maximum and a minimum value in the array.
- Before:

  ```
  int array[MAX_SIZE];
  size_t actual_size;
  // array and actual_size initialised here
  ...
  // Want to extract this piece of code
  // Both maxVal and minVal are initialised inside
  // and need to be used outside afterwards
  int maxVal = array[0], minVal = array[0];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < actual_size; i++) {
     if (array[i] > maxVal) maxVal = array[i];
     else if (array[i] < minVal) minVal = array[i];
  }
  ```
- After:

  ```
  // Min and max values are passed by pointer
  // They are so-called output parameters
  void findMinMax(const int* array, size_t size, int* pMaxVal, int* pMinVal) {
    *pMaxVal = array[0];
    *pMinVal = array[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < actual_size; i++) {
      if (array[i] > *pMaxVal) *pMaxVal = array[i];
      else if (array[i] < *pMinVal) *pMinVal = array[i];
    }
  }
  ...
  int maxVal, minVal;
  findMinMax(array, actual_size, &maxVal, &minVal);
  ```

4. Finally, there is a technique of passing data between functions by using a global/static variable. Don't use it.